TeXStudio Embedded PDF viewer - grey space lateral margins
Using TexStudio and its embedded PDF viewer, how can one toggle on/off the grey margins to the right and left of the paper?
Having hit a wrong button, it turned into an "infinity" mode, where page margins are no longer shown.

Is your page scaled to fit the window? If yes, zoom out to get the margins back

Thank you, but, now, this is sadly not the problem. Page separations from one page to the next are still shown, though, the left/right margins are now white, like so

Maybe a problem with the texstudio version https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/discussions/3656

Thank you very much indeed.
Updated to 4.8.1 and it is gone. It is still uncanny, that the margins "disappeared" when I wildly, mistakenly so, stupid as I am, my mouse buttons.
If you post it as a answer, I can accept it.
Either way, to reiterate, thank you oh so much.

I keep my fingers crossed that the margins stay gray :) Please feel free to post an answer yourself. You know best which versions you had/have etc.

As graciously pointed out by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, it presumably was due to an issue under TexStudio version 4.8.0 | Windows 11 23H2 22631.3672 (May 2024).
Updating to 4.8.1 resolved the issue.
